# Sonar violation around JavaScript arguments object usage

Tags: javascript, sonarqube

Let's say I have the following JavaScript code in my project:

```
function foo(){
  console.log(arguments);         
}
```

When I run the Sonar JavaScript plugin across it, it registers the following error:

> "eval" and "arguments" must not be bound or assigned

Any idea why? I understand this error should only occur if  `arguments` is assigned to a variable or it is used as a parameter name, but neither is the case here.

Comment: Maybe you should report a bug or switch over to another code quality management platform.

Answer (score 1):

The description of the rule in Sonar explains it quite clear: "arguments" is an implicit variable that give access to the arguments of the function, and that is an indexed property. So this is unlikely that you want to pass this variable like what you're showing (which looks like a debug code only), and most of the time doing so should raise attention (only technical JS stacks/frameworks should require to do so).

Answer (score 1):

There is a bug already reported for this issue, as stated here:-
http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONARPLUGINS-2843

1.4 sonar javascript plugin is expected to release on Aug 15.